# How to find distance between face encodings when stored multiple for the same person, in THIS scenario... ( Python )

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

**I** am working on a project based on the facial recognition and verification.
**I** am using Siamese network to get the 128 vector of the face ( Embeddings ).

**I** am storing the encodings/embeddings of the person's face in the database and then checking or say matching the incoming face's encodings with the previously stored encodings to recognize the person.

To make a robust system, I have to store more than one encodings of the same person.
When I have used only a single encoding vector, and matched with :

`face_recognition.compare_faces( stored_list_of_encodings, checking_image_encodings )`

That dosen't work **all the time** because I have only compared with a single encoding.
To make a system sufficient for most cases, I want to store minimum 3 encodings of a same person and then compare with the new data.

Now the question :

> How to store multiple embeddings of a same person and then compare the distance ?

Please Help me with this...

( Using *face_recognition* as the library and *Siamese Network* for feature extraction )

Comment: is your source set of images limited? what i mean is , do u actually have 3 slightly different pose/face of the same person ? then the embeddings generally are true. Else you can augment the single source face, to some perspective transformation, (not too much of deformation) and generate the embeddings and make sure the distance(cosine distance) is with in your threshold for making it same face.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get encoding of each images of person you can use face_encodings function of face_recognition library, then by comparing distance between these encodings you can improve your system in your own way.

for example:

```
encoding_1 = face_recognition.face_encodings(img_1)
encoding_2 = face_recognition.face_encodings(img_2)
encoding_3 = face_recognition.face_encodings(img_3)

encodings = [encoding_1,encoding_2,encoding3]

new_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(new_image)

for encoding in encodings:
    #to look at distance between two encoding vector, you can use numpy linear algebra functions (you can also use other distance metrics)
    distance = np.linalg.norm(new_encoding - encoding)
    
    if distance < threshold:
        return True
```

Comment: In face recognition (the science) and in face_recognition (the python library), is there any concept where multiple photos of the same person can be combined to make a more reliable "encoding"?  The above answer makes an encoding for each photo,  so if 7 persons are enrolled, each with 3 photos, then there are 21 encodings total to store, and to check against.  The system doesn't take advantage of the information that each person is enrolled with 3 different photos.

Answer (score 0):

## How do I compare multiple faces per person

Given that your database looks something like:

```
face_table {
    'person_name' : String,
    'embedding' : Array of 128 floats,
    'other_data' : Something,
    ...
}
```

and you have a function

```
face_recognition.compare_faces(encoding_list, reference_encoding)
```

which returns a probability score per element of `encoding_list` and how well it matches the `referene_encoding`.

and your main loop does something like

```
name_list, encoding_list = zip(query_database_for_encodings())
results = face_recognition.compare_faces(encoding_list, reference_encoding)
best = np.argmax(results)
return name_list[best]
```

## Solution 1 - add records

In this solution you can simply add multiple records to your database for the same person.

```
{ # record 1
    'person_name' : 'Alice',
    'embedding' : Array of 128 floats,
    'photo_number' : 1
}
{ # record 2
    'person_name' : 'Alice',
    'embedding' : Array of 128 floats,
    'photo_number' : 2
}
{ # record 3
    'person_name' : 'Bob',
    'embedding' : Array of 128 floats,
    'photo_number' : 1
}
```

and so on having multiple records per person.

## Solution 2 - Store an array of embeddings

In this solution you just have an array of embeddings per person in the database like so

```
face_table {
    'person_name' : String,
    'embedding_list' : Array of (Array of 128 floats),
    'other_data' : Something,
    ...
}
```

and your other main loop code just changes to handle it possibly like so

```
records = query_database_returning_dictionary_results()

def generate_name_embedding_pairs(records):
    for record in records:
        name = record['person_name']
        for encoding_list in record['embedding_list']:
            yield name, encoding_list

name_list, encoding_list = zip(list(generate_name_embedding_pairs(records)))
results = face_recognition.compare_faces(encoding_list, reference_encoding)
best = np.argmax(results)
return name_list[best]
```